# xsd validate xml variables against different section of the same document

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

Not sure if this is possible but I would like to validate with xsd (version 1.1) that variables used in an xml document are specified in a different section of the same document.

One section of my document looks like this:

```
<bf:Variables>
    <bf:Variable name="myVariable">
        ...
    </bf:Variable>
    <bf:Variable name="AnotherOne">
        ...
    </bf:Variable>
    <bf:Variable name="evenMore">
        ...
    </bf:Variable>
    ...
</bf:Variables>
```

Then in the same document I have another section that looks like this:

```
<bf:Restrictions>
    <bf:Restriction variable="myVariable" operator="=">
        <bf:Value>True</bf:Value>
    </bf:Restriction>
    <bf:Restriction variable="AnotherOne" operator="=">
        <bf:Value>False</bf:Value>
    </bf:Restriction>
    <bf:Restriction variable="ThirdVariable" operator="=">
        <bf:Value>False</bf:Value>
    </bf:Restriction>
</bf:Restrictions>
```

My goal is to check that the variables used in the restriction section are specified in the variables section.
In the above example "ThirdVariable" should fail the xsd check as it doesn't exist in the Variables section.

Answer (score 0):

This can be tackled in a few ways, some better than others

**A Solution using assert - but not a great one...**

In XSD 1.1 you can do this using an `<xs:assert>`. Ideally the assert would be placed on the referencing element `<Restriction>`, this would then make it obvious which `<Restriction>` is invalid.

However, because the `<xs:assert>` can not access values higher up in the tree the `<xs:assert>` has to be high enough up to have the `<Restriction>` and the `<Variable>` within its scope (children of). This has would be fine, but now you have to write a general rule, which if it fails will not provide much feedback - it will simply tell you one or more of the `<Restriction>` is invalid.

Heres a very quick sample to demonstrate.

[image: Visual representation of the schema made with Liquid XML Studio]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition 15.0.0.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="base">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="var" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="Usage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="count(Usage[not(./text() = ../var/text())]) = 0" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2016 Developer Bundle Edition 14.1.4.6649 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<base xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Schema.xsd">
    <var>var1</var>
    <var>var2</var>
    <var>var4</var>
    <Usage>var1</Usage>
    <Usage>var2</Usage>
    <Usage>var3</Usage><!-- INVALID -->
</base>
```

**Error Message (via Saxon)**

(10:7) Critical cvc-assertion: Assertion evaluation ('count(Usage[not(./text() = ../var/text())]) = 0') for element 'base' on schema type '#AnonType_base' did not succeed.

**A Better Solution using Key/KeyRef's**

This is XSD 1.0 friendly and works pretty well. It tells you if you have duplicate varaible names and also if a variable name reference is invalid, pointing you at the actual issue.

[image: Visual representation of the key keyref schema from Liquid XML Studio]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition 15.0.0.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="base">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Variables">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Variable" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Restrictions">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Restriction" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="variable" type="xs:string" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="VarDef">
            <xs:selector xpath="./Variables/Variable" />
            <xs:field xpath="@name" />
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="VarRef" refer="VarDef">
            <xs:selector xpath="./Restrictions/Restriction" />
            <xs:field xpath="@variable" />
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2017 Developer Bundle Edition 15.0.0.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<base xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SchemaKeyRef.xsd">
    <Variables>
        <Variable name="var1"></Variable>
        <Variable name="var2"></Variable>
        <Variable name="var3"></Variable>
    </Variables>
    <Restrictions>
        <Restriction variable="var1">string</Restriction>
        <Restriction variable="var2">string</Restriction>
        <Restriction variable="UNKNOWN">string</Restriction>
    </Restrictions>
</base>
```

Now the error generated is much more specific, making debugging the issue much easier.

**Error From .Net (The line number is the bad Restriction)**

(12:10) Error The key sequence 'UNKNOWN' in 'VarDef' Keyref fails to refer to some key.

**Error from Saxon (The line number is the containing element base)**

(14:7) Critical cvc-identity-constraint.4.3: Key 'VarRef' with value 'UNKNOWN' not found for identity constraint of element 'base'.